# Python validate_email TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, module, python-module

I want to use validate_email module:

```
from validate_email import validate_email
is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True)
```

But I got exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Рабочий стол/Проекты/emailtxt/me.py", line 2, in <module>
    is_valid = validate_email('example@example.com',verify=True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/validate_email/validate_email.py", line 70, in validate_email
    return validate_email_or_fail(email_address, **kwargs)
TypeError: validate_email_or_fail() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You appear to trying to use example code `validate_email`, but have `py3-validate-email` installed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I deleted py3-validate-email, but now I get only None :(

Answer (score 0):

i think this https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues/113 library dont work

you can use: https://github.com/karolyi/py3-validate-email

Comment: 02:29:30.265634 send: 'quit\r\n'
02:29:30.265896 connect: to ('alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', 25) None
02:29:40.275959 send: 'quit\r\n'
02:29:40.276307 connect: to ('alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com', 25) None
None
02:29:50.284531 send: 'quit\r\n'